# Using Intel's RdRand opcode in Delphi 6/7

Tags: delphi, assembly, random, opcode, rdrand

is there a way to use Intel's RdRand opcode in older Delphi versions like 6 or 7?

Maybe using

asm
  db $...
end;

or something? How do I store the number into a variable?

Speed is very important. I can't use an external library for this.

Comment: Yes, you can use db. The opcode is documented in the Intel hardware manual. What's stopping you from doing this?

Comment: How do I get the random number into a variable? Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to test this since my processor doesn't support RdRand, but this should get you going:

```
function RdRand: Cardinal;
asm
  db  $0f
  db  $c7
  db  $f0
end;
```

The opcode for RdRand is 0x0f 0xc7 and the ModR/M value of `0xf0` puts the output into EAX, the function return value.

Now, this is incomplete. You must also [check the value of the carry flag to determine whether or not the RdRand execution succeeded](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide).

> After invoking the RDRAND instruction, the caller must examine the carry flag (CF) to determine whether a random value was available at the time the RDRAND instruction was executed. As Table 3 shows, a value of 1 indicates that a random value was available and placed in the destination register provided in the invocation. A value of 0 indicates that a random value was not available. In current architectures the destination register will also be zeroed as a side effect of this condition.

So that might lead you to code like this:

```
function TryRdRand(out Value: Cardinal): Boolean;
asm
  db   $0f
  db   $c7
  db   $f1
  jc   @success
  xor  eax,eax
  ret
@success:
  mov  [eax],ecx
  mov  eax,1
end;
```

Again I cannot test it, but I hope it helps you on the way. The ModR/M of 0xf1 puts the output value into ecx which I then copy into [eax] if the operation succeeded.

The above linked documentation goes on to say:

> It is recommended that applications attempt 10 retries in a tight loop in the unlikely event that the RDRAND instruction does not return a random number. This number is based on a binomial probability argument: given the design margins of the DRNG, the odds of ten failures in a row are astronomically small and would in fact be an indication of a larger CPU issue.

You can readily implement this retry policy on top of the function above.

Finally, I'm sure you are aware, but you must make calls to CPUID to check that the processor supports RdRand.

Comment: @LURD Thanks a lot for the help. I think I'm there now. Much appreciated.

Comment: I did not test the second code, but since the first one is sufficient for my application, this is the "correct answer". Thanks!

Comment: @blubb if the CPU doesnt support RdRand then you program will break down.

By the way the Delphi version af ramdom i remarkable faster

Comment: @Jens System.Random does something else

Comment: You are right @DavidHeffernan the current edit will is fine. Bu it wasn't when i wrote my comment.

Comment: @Jens OK that's good, thanks for testing, guess I need a newer processor!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How about `x64` ?

Comment: @John question was about x86, for D6/7. On x64 the address would arrive in rcx, iirc. Otherwise it would be much the same. You'd need to tweak it for 64 output, as per Intel docs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan done, and after it is all cleaned up, then I'll delete tis comment as well :D